# COM issue 800A01AD only on server

Tags: c#-4.0, com-interop, typelib

I have a .NET library that I'm trying to use via COM (hMailServer's VBScript scripts).  I got it all working on my local, development box (Windows 7 x64).  However, after copying the DLL to my server (Windows Server 2008 x64) I keep getting the following error when the VBScript runs:

> Error: 800A01AD - Description: ActiveX
>   component can't create object:
>   'hMailServerPlugins.EventHandlers' -
>   Line: 2 Column: 1 - Code: (null)"

I've given the assembly a strong name.  I put the assembly in the same directory as hMailServer and I've registered it using

> regasm hMailServerPlugins.dll
>   /codebase /tlb:hMailServer.tlb

the references show up in the assembly too!  I've even tried changing the hMailServer service to startup using Administrator user credentials to make sure this isn't a security thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this for Antoine and anyone else who might stumble upon this thread.

It turned out that I had to explicitly call the 64bit *regasm* to properly register the library.  The location on my machine is

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe

Hope that helps

Comment: In my case registering to Framework64 did not work, I had to register to c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe, note the non 64 in the framework folder name.